# Migration SQL ERROR 1062 (23000) Duplicate entry 'NULL'

Tags: database, migration

I'm trying to move a live site to a dev server. Export SQL has been done with phpmyadmin. When importing via CLI;
mysql -u "user" -p "name_new_database" < bupsqlfile.sql

I get this error:
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 4659855: Duplicate entry 'NULL' for key 'sales_order_grid.SALES_ORDER_GRID_PICKUP_LOCATION_CODE'

The part where the line number refers to :

> `-- -- Indexes for table` sales_order_grid`-- ALTER TABLE`sales_order_grid `ADD PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY` SALES_ORDER_GRID_INCREMENT_ID_STORE_ID `(`increment_id`,`store_id`), ADD KEY` SALES_ORDER_GRID_STATUS `(`status`), ADD KEY` SALES_ORDER_GRID_STORE_ID `(`store_id`), ADD KEY` SALES_ORDER_GRID_BASE_GRAND_TOTAL `(`base_grand_total`), ADD KEY` SALES_ORDER_GRID_BASE_TOTAL_PAID `(`base_total_paid`), ADD KEY` SALES_ORDER_GRID_GRAND_TOTAL `(`grand_total`), ADD KEY` SALES_ORDER_GRID_TOTAL_PAID `(`total_paid`), ADD KEY` SALES_ORDER_GRID_SHIPPING_NAME `(`shipping_name`), ADD KEY` SALES_ORDER_GRID_BILLING_NAME `(`billing_name`), ADD KEY` SALES_ORDER_GRID_CREATED_AT `(`created_at`), ADD KEY` SALES_ORDER_GRID_CUSTOMER_ID `(`customer_id`), ADD KEY` SALES_ORDER_GRID_UPDATED_AT `(`updated_at`), ADD KEY` SALES_ORDER_GRID_PICKUP_LOCATION_CODE `(`pickup_location_code`); ALTER TABLE` sales_order_grid`ADD FULLTEXT KEY`FTI_randomkeygoeshere `(`increment_id`,`billing_name`,`shipping_name`,`shipping_address`,`billing_address`,`customer_name`,`customer_email`);`

When I look in the table "sales_order_grid" most records have the value "null" in the key "pickup_location_code"

What can I do to go ahead with the import?

I've tried disabling the foreign key check, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lesson learned...  I shouldn't have done the export via phpmyadmin...

Done the export via CLI and solved it!